# maven repository for LinearRegressionModel

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to launch samples from spark tutorial and I can't get this compiled:

```
final LinearRegressionModel model =
             LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(JavaRDD.toRDD(parsedData),numIterations, stepSize);
```

I can't find maven dependency and import package for `LinearRegressionWithSGD`. This one doesn't work:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
```

Which should I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `spark-mllib` library :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```